# Unable to generate Cucumber html report with selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I'm currently using Cucumber Framework with Selenium Java.I have updated the Pom xml file.

1. There are Java 11,
2. Selenium-java 4.2.2,
3. webdreivermanager 5.2.1,
4. cucumber java 7.3.4,
5. cucumber junit 7.3.4 dependencies in the pom xml file.

**I also downloaded**

6. maven-resources-plugin 3.1.0,
7. maven-failsafe-plugin 3.0.0-M4,
8. maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M7 and
9. maven-cucumber-reporting 5.0.0 as Plugin.

When I run the tests after the update, only the results of **Failed** ones are shown in the `cucumber` `html report` or the results of some Testcases from different classes are displayed. **I can't see the result of all the tests**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/runners/Smoke1TestRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>

            <configuration>

                <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
                <threadCount>${se.threadCount}</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/runners/Smoke1TestRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>     
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <param>**/json-reports/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <classificationFiles>
                        <param>sample.properties</param>
                        <param>other.properties</param>
                    </classificationFiles>
                        <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                    </configuration>
                </execution></executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: can you please paste what you have tried so far

Comment: @Sonali Das  I pasted

Comment: Please paste the code of your runner file